# Can someone help me with lsp C++20 features recognition?

Tags: c++, lsp, clang

Lsp clangd does not recognise c++20 features in my Emacs. I use flycheck and it highlights something as

```cpp
import <iostream>
```

`std::format` is not supported either and so on. Can someone tell me how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a question about Emacs, but about clangd. The whole point of LSP, or the Language Server Protocol, is that it is a standard protocol editors can use to talk to Language Servers like clangd. Since there are many languages and many programs that act as language servers, all of them are configured differently. You will need to consult the [documentation for clangd](https://clangd.llvm.org/config).